# Not able to perform scroll in appium 1.14.16 on Android using python

Tags: android, appium, python-appium

This is my code

```
desired_caps = {}
desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '4.4.2'
desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'Gaurav'
# Returns abs path relative to this file and not cwd
#desired_caps['app'] = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'ApiDemos-debug.apk'))
desired_caps['app'] = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'ragga.apk'))
driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
driver.implicitly_wait(100)
driver.find_element_by_id('com.raaga.android:id/skip_text').click()
driver.find_element_by_id('com.raaga.android:id/landing_skip_to_raaga').click()
driver.find_element_by_name('Hindi').click()
e1 = driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new UiSelector().text("Most Popular")')
e2 = driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new UiSelector().text("Remix")')
print e1,e2
driver.scroll(e1, e2)
```

I want to perform the scroll but on screen it is not performing any action for it.
This is the screenshot of android device

[image]

And below are the Appium server logs:

> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Registered crash watchers.
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Client connected
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"wake","params":{}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: wake
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":true,"status":0}
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 4d001f6ab48f90e9 shell "dumpsys window"
>   info: [debug] Screen already unlocked, continuing.
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["getDataDir",{}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"getDataDir","params":{}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getDataDir
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":"/data/local/tmp","status":0}
>   info: [debug] dataDir set to: /data/local/tmp
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["compressedLayoutHierarchy",{"compressLayout":false}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"compressedLayoutHierarchy","params":{"compressLayout":false}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: compressedLayoutHierarchy
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":false,"status":0}
>   info: [debug] Getting device API level
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 4d001f6ab48f90e9 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
>   info: [debug] Device is at API Level 19
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 4d001f6ab48f90e9 shell "am start -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000 -n com.raaga.android/com.raaga.android.SplashScreen"
>   info: [debug] Waiting for pkg "com.raaga.android" and activity "com.raaga.android.SplashScreen" to be focused
>   info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 4d001f6ab48f90e9 shell "dumpsys window windows"
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 4d001f6ab48f90e9 shell "getprop ro.build.version.release"
>   info: [debug] Device is at release version 4.4.2
>   info: [debug] Device launched! Ready for commands
>   info: [debug] Setting command timeout to the default of 60 secs
>   info: [debug] Appium session started with sessionId 2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 303 16699.167 ms - 74 
>   info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0 {}
>   info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"platform":"LINUX","browserName":"Android","platformVersion":"4.4.2","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"platformVersion":"4.4.2","deviceName":"Gaurav","app":"C:\Users\Gaurav.Kumar-admin\PycharmProjects\NewTest\Learning\thirtyday\apps\ragga.apk","platformName":"Android"},"deviceName":"4d001f6ab48f90e9","app":"C:\Users\Gaurav.Kumar-admin\PycharmProjects\NewTest\Learning\thirtyday\apps\ragga.apk","platformName":"Android"},"sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0"}
>   info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0 200 4.702 ms - 663 {"status":0,"value":{"platform":"LINUX","browserName":"Android","platformVersion":"4.4.2","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"platformVersion":"4.4.2","deviceName":"Gaurav","app":"C:\Users\Gaurav.Kumar-admin\PycharmProjects\NewTest\Learning\thirtyday\apps\ragga.apk","platformName":"Android"},"deviceName":"4d001f6ab48f90e9","app":"C:\Users\Gaurav.Kumar-admin\PycharmProjects\NewTest\Learning\thirtyday\apps\ragga.apk","platformName":"Android"},"sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0"}
>   info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0/timeouts/implicit_wait {"sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0","ms":100000}
>   info: [debug] Set Android implicit wait to 100000ms
>   info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":null,"sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0"}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0/timeouts/implicit_wait 200 2.776 ms - 76 {"status":0,"value":null,"sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0"}
>   info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0/element {"using":"id","sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0","value":"com.raaga.android:id/skip_text"}
>   info: [debug] Waiting up to 100000ms for condition
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.raaga.android:id/skip_text","context":"","multiple":false}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.raaga.android:id/skip_text","context":"","multiple":false}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding com.raaga.android:id/skip_text using ID with the contextId:  multiple: false
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.raaga.android:id/skip_text]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Failed to locate element. Clearing Accessibility cache and retrying.
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding com.raaga.android:id/skip_text using ID with the contextId:  multiple: false
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.raaga.android:id/skip_text]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":"No element found","status":7}
>   info: [debug] Waited for 911ms so far
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.raaga.android:id/skip_text","context":"","multiple":false}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.raaga.android:id/skip_text","context":"","multiple":false}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding com.raaga.android:id/skip_text using ID with the contextId:  multiple: false
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.raaga.android:id/skip_text]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Failed to locate element. Clearing Accessibility cache and retrying.
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding com.raaga.android:id/skip_text using ID with the contextId:  multiple: false
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.raaga.android:id/skip_text]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":"No element found","status":7}
>   info: [debug] Waited for 1510ms so far
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.raaga.android:id/skip_text","context":"","multiple":false}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.raaga.android:id/skip_text","context":"","multiple":false}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding com.raaga.android:id/skip_text using ID with the contextId:  multiple: false
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.raaga.android:id/skip_text]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Failed to locate element. Clearing Accessibility cache and retrying.
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding com.raaga.android:id/skip_text using ID with the contextId:  multiple: false
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.raaga.android:id/skip_text]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":"No element found","status":7}
>   info: [debug] Waited for 2023ms so far
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.raaga.android:id/skip_text","context":"","multiple":false}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.raaga.android:id/skip_text","context":"","multiple":false}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding com.raaga.android:id/skip_text using ID with the contextId:  multiple: false
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.raaga.android:id/skip_text]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Failed to locate element. Clearing Accessibility cache and retrying.
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding com.raaga.android:id/skip_text using ID with the contextId:  multiple: false
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.raaga.android:id/skip_text]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":"No element found","status":7}
>   info: [debug] Waited for 2612ms so far
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.raaga.android:id/skip_text","context":"","multiple":false}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.raaga.android:id/skip_text","context":"","multiple":false}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding com.raaga.android:id/skip_text using ID with the contextId:  multiple: false
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.raaga.android:id/skip_text]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":{"ELEMENT":"1"},"status":0}
>   info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"1"},"sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0"}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0/element 200 4407.689 ms - 87 {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"1"},"sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0"}
>   info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0/element/1/click {"sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0","id":"1"}
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:click",{"elementId":"1"}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:click","params":{"elementId":"1"}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: click
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":true,"status":0}
>   info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0"}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0/element/1/click 200 1047.512 ms - 76 {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0"}
>   info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0/element {"using":"id","sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0","value":"com.raaga.android:id/landing_skip_to_raaga"}
>   info: [debug] Waiting up to 100000ms for condition
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.raaga.android:id/landing_skip_to_raaga","context":"","multiple":false}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.raaga.android:id/landing_skip_to_raaga","context":"","multiple":false}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding com.raaga.android:id/landing_skip_to_raaga using ID with the contextId:  multiple: false
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.raaga.android:id/landing_skip_to_raaga]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":{"ELEMENT":"2"},"status":0}
>   info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"2"},"sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0"}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0/element 200 628.651 ms - 87 {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"2"},"sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0"}
>   info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0/element/2/click {"sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0","id":"2"}
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:click",{"elementId":"2"}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:click","params":{"elementId":"2"}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: click
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":true,"status":0}
>   info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0"}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0/element/2/click 200 2494.108 ms - 76 {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0"}
>   info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0/element {"using":"name","sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0","value":"Hindi"}
>   warn: [DEPRECATED] The name locator strategy has been deprecated and will be removed.  Please use the accessibility id locator strategy instead.
>   info: [debug] Waiting up to 100000ms for condition
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"name","selector":"Hindi","context":"","multiple":false}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"name","selector":"Hindi","context":"","multiple":false}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding Hindi using NAME with the contextId:  multiple: false
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[DESCRIPTION=Hindi, INSTANCE=0]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[TEXT=Hindi, INSTANCE=0]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":{"ELEMENT":"3"},"status":0}
>   info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"3"},"sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0"}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0/element 200 1064.529 ms - 87 {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"3"},"sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0"}
>   info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0/element/3/click {"sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0","id":"3"}
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:click",{"elementId":"3"}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:click","params":{"elementId":"3"}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: click
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":true,"status":0}
>   info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0"}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0/element/3/click 200 1170.488 ms - 76 {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0"}
>   info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0/element {"using":"-android uiautomator","sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0","value":"new UiSelector().text(\"Most Popular\")"}
>   info: [debug] Waiting up to 100000ms for condition
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"-android uiautomator","selector":"new UiSelector().text(\"Most Popular\")","context":"","multiple":false}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"-android uiautomator","selector":"new UiSelector().text(\"Most Popular\")","context":"","multiple":false}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding new UiSelector().text("Most Popular") using ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR with the contextId:  multiple: false
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Parsing selector: new UiSelector().text("Most Popular")
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] UiSelector coerce type: class java.lang.String arg: "Most Popular"
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[TEXT=Most Popular]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Failed to locate element. Clearing Accessibility cache and retrying.
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding new UiSelector().text("Most Popular") using ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR with the contextId:  multiple: false
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Parsing selector: new UiSelector().text("Most Popular")
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] UiSelector coerce type: class java.lang.String arg: "Most Popular"
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[TEXT=Most Popular]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":"No element found","status":7}
>   info: [debug] Waited for 115ms so far
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"-android uiautomator","selector":"new UiSelector().text(\"Most Popular\")","context":"","multiple":false}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"-android uiautomator","selector":"new UiSelector().text(\"Most Popular\")","context":"","multiple":false}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding new UiSelector().text("Most Popular") using ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR with the contextId:  multiple: false
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Parsing selector: new UiSelector().text("Most Popular")
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] UiSelector coerce type: class java.lang.String arg: "Most Popular"
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[TEXT=Most Popular]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":{"ELEMENT":"4"},"status":0}
>   info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"4"},"sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0"}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0/element 200 889.782 ms - 87 {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"4"},"sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0"}
>   info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0/element {"using":"-android uiautomator","sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0","value":"new UiSelector().text(\"Remix\")"}
>   info: [debug] Waiting up to 100000ms for condition
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"-android uiautomator","selector":"new UiSelector().text(\"Remix\")","context":"","multiple":false}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"-android uiautomator","selector":"new UiSelector().text(\"Remix\")","context":"","multiple":false}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding new UiSelector().text("Remix") using ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR with the contextId:  multiple: false
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Parsing selector: new UiSelector().text("Remix")
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] UiSelector coerce type: class java.lang.String arg: "Remix"
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[TEXT=Remix]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":{"ELEMENT":"5"},"status":0}
>   info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"5"},"sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0"}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0/element 200 1261.892 ms - 87 {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"5"},"sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0"}
>   info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0/touch/perform {"sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0","actions":[{"action":"press","options":{"y":null,"x":null,"element":"4"}},{"action":"moveTo","options":{"y":null,"x":null,"element":"5"}},{"action":"release","options":{}}]}
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:getLocation",{"elementId":"5"}]
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:getSize",{"elementId":"5"}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:getLocation","params":{"elementId":"5"}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getLocation
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":{"y":1182,"x":525},"status":0}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:getSize","params":{"elementId":"5"}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getSize
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":{"height":44,"width":118},"status":0}
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:getLocation",{"elementId":"4"}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:getLocation","params":{"elementId":"4"}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getLocation
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":{"y":726,"x":478},"status":0}
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:getSize",{"elementId":"4"}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:getSize","params":{"elementId":"4"}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getSize
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":{"height":76,"width":212},"status":0}
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:getLocation",{"elementId":"5"}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:getLocation","params":{"elementId":"5"}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getLocation
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":{"y":1182,"x":525},"status":0}
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:getSize",{"elementId":"5"}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:getSize","params":{"elementId":"5"}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getSize
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":{"height":44,"width":118},"status":0}
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:touchDown",{"elementId":"4","x":584,"y":764}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:touchDown","params":{"elementId":"4","x":584,"y":764}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: touchDown
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Performing TouchDown using element? true x: 584, y: 764
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":true,"status":0}
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:touchMove",{"elementId":"5","x":584,"y":1204}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:touchMove","params":{"elementId":"5","x":584,"y":1204}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: touchMove
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Performing TouchMove using element? true x: 584, y: 1204
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":true,"status":0}
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:touchUp",{"elementId":"5","x":584,"y":1204}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:touchUp","params":{"elementId":"5","x":584,"y":1204}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: touchUp
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Performing TouchUp using element? true x: 584, y: 1204
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":true,"status":0}
>   info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0"}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0/touch/perform 200 1912.002 ms - 76 {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"2c7f4312-23aa-4b5d-8b65-ae1f012797d0"}

Also can some one please help in scrolling the screen when the element till which you want to scroll the hidden below the current screen view

Comment: what do you want exactly ..... scroll down the page or move one element to another?

Comment: @noor I want to scroll down the page.

Answer (score 0):

First, u can do it by below:

```
//Scroll till element which contains "Views" text If It Is not visible on screen.
driver.scrollTo("Views");

// Scroll till element which contains Tabs text.
driver.scrollTo("Tabs");
```

This is the very simples way u can try. If this does not help you, u can try the below code:

```
Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize(); 
int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.80); 
//Find endy point which is at top side of screen. 
int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.20);
//int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.10);
//Find horizontal point where you wants to swipe. It is in middle of screen width. 
int startx = size.width / 2; 

//Swipe from Bottom to Top. 
driver.swipe(startx, starty, startx, endy, 3000);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

// create a method name scrollTo or any name of your choice , with below mentioned code it will take parameter of text using which we want to scroll : (Note : this is in java you can convert as per python syntax)

```
public void scrollTo(String text)
{                
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\""+text+"\").instance(0))");
}
```